# AWS SQS Integration - SQS receive message failed: Could not load credentials from any providers

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, nestjs, amazon-sqs

I'm working on integrating AWS SQS (Simple Queue Service) into my NestJS application using the @ssut/nestjs-sqs package. However, I'm encountering an error when trying to receive messages from the SQS queue.

```
/Users/avinash.anshu/Project/Practice/amazon-sqs-nest/node_modules/sqs-consumer/dist/errors.js:40
    const sqsError = new SQSError(message);
                     ^
SQSError: SQS receive message failed: Could not load credentials from any providers
    at toSQSError (/Users/avinash.anshu/Project/Practice/amazon-sqs-nest/node_modules/sqs-consumer/dist/errors.js:40:22)
    at Consumer.receiveMessage (/Users/avinash.anshu/Project/Practice/amazon-sqs-nest/node_modules/sqs-consumer/dist/consumer.js:173:43)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

My setup includes the following:

- I'm using NestJS as the framework for my application.
- I have installed the @ssut/nestjs-sqs package to interact with AWS SQS queues.
- I have configured my config object, which includes the necessary AWS region and queue details.

**Code**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { SqsMessageHandler } from '@ssut/nestjs-sqs';
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import { config } from '../config';

console.log('config.AWS_REGION', config);

@Injectable()
export class MessageHandler {
    constructor() { }

    @SqsMessageHandler(config.TEST_QUEUE, false)
    async handleMessage(message: AWS.SQS.Message) {
        const obj: any = JSON.parse(message.Body) as {
            message: string;
            date: string;
        };
        const { data } = JSON.parse(obj.Message);
        console.log(data);

        // use the data and consume it the way you want //
    }
}
```

When attempting to receive messages from the SQS queue using the @SqsMessageHandler, I encounter the SQSError: SQS receive message failed: Could not load credentials from any providers error.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running this code from within an EC2 instance so you should not disable IMDSv1 when using older AWS-SDK versions. Older sdk versions uses IMDSv1 to get EC2 metadata.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-ec2-imds.html